# Is there is any other solution to login method with multiple users?

Tags: java, web, authentication, multiple-users

I am creating a website with multiple users , here is the code i created but it does not work , what is the correct ?

This is a java Project, Java se

```
public String Login() {
    for(Employees emp1 : Employees.theAllEmp) {
        if(emp1.getEmail().equals(emp.getEmail())) {
            if(emp1.getPassword().equals(emp.getPassword())) {
                if (emp1.getAdmin() == 0) {
                    return "adminView.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
                } else if (emp1.getAdmin() == 1) {
                    return "employeesView.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
                } else {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "No such Email", "No such Email"));
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: "It does not work". what do you mean, it does not work? does it give compile time errors? run time errors? error messages? stacktrace? unexpected  behaviour?

Comment: also:where is your emp variable coming from?

Comment: Your passwords don't seem to be encrypted, but they should be (you chould compare sha1 for instance, and not real password). Consider using a LDAP to handle authentication

Comment: @jaudo not that you're wrong, but I think it's the OP's first time trying to create a simple login for a simple application. I would suggest this as a goal to achieve once she's got the hang of the basics

Comment: Stultuske  : 
the method always return null ,

Comment: emp is an object from bojo class